# Python Bokeh: Plotting same chart multiple times in gridplot

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm currently trying to get an overview of plots of data of different dates. To get a good feeling of the data I would like to plot relevant plots next to each other. This means I want to use the same plot multiple times in the gridplot command. However what I noticed is that when i use the same chart multiple times it will only show it once in the final .html file. My first attempt at solving this was to use a copy.deepcopy for the charts, but this gave the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot get a property value 'label' from a LineGlyph instance before HasProps.__init__
```

My approach has been as follows:

```
from bokeh.charts import Line, output_file, show, gridplot
import pandas as pd
output_file('test.html')
plots = []

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,1], [2,2]])
print(df)
df.columns = ['x', 'y']
for i in range(10):
    plots.append(Line(df, x='x', y='y', title='Forecast: ' + str(i),
                 plot_width=250, plot_height=250))

plot_matrix = []
for i in range(len(plots)-1, 2, -1):
    plot_matrix.append([plots[i-3], plots[i-2], plots[i]])
p = gridplot(plot_matrix)
show(p)
```

The results of which is a an html page with a grid plot with a lot of missing graphs. Each graph is exactly shown once (instead of the 3 times required), which leads me to think that the gridplot does not like me using the same object multiple times. An obvious solve is to simply create every graph 3 times as a different object, which I will do for now, but not only is this inefficient, it also hurts my eyes when looking at my code. I'm hoping somebody has a more elegant solution for my problem.

EDIT: made code runable

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Bokeh plots (or Bokeh objects in general) may not be re-used in layouts.